# Group acting by isometries on a length space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, group-actions, metric-geometry

I am reading the book [A course in metric geometry](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/bbi.pdf) by Burago, Burago and Ivanov.
I have some difficulties with an exercise 3.4.6 on page 78. The exercise is the following: Let a group $G$ act by isometries on a length space $X$. Assume that all the orbits are discrete. Prove that the projection map $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ is a local isometry at a point $x$ if and only if $x$ is not fixed by a nonidentity element of $G$.

I could prove one direction, namely that if $x$ is not fixed by a nonidentity element of $G$ then $p$ is a local isometry. 
For the other direction I have no idea how to do. Does anyone have an idea how to do it, or a hint?

Thanks,
Maurice

Comment: This seems to be false. What if $G$ acts trivially, say?

Comment: @Chris: The authors implicitly assume that $G$ acts effectively, so they're ruling out this objection.

Answer (score 4):

I think the statement is wrong: Consider the subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^2$ that is the union of the two coordinate axes equipped with the induced intrinsic metric;
$$X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ | x = 0\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ | y = 0\}.$$
This is clearly a length space. Now consider the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $X$ via reflecting at the $y$-axis (the one coming from the involution $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$). Then the action on $X$ is effective, isometric and the $y$-axis equals the fixed point set of the action. It follows easily that $p : X \to X/\mathbb Z_2$ is a local isometry at every point of the $y$-axis different from $(0,0)$.

Edit: It is not hard to see, that the statement is true for, say, manifolds.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}^2$ do you mean the group with two elements?

Comment: @AlpUzman exactly